# MS Excel VBA how to insert a row in the current worksheet and three others

Tags: excel, vba

I am using MS Excel 2007 and Microsoft Visula Basic 6.5.

I want to select a row in a sheet and then use a macro to insert a row in this sheet and three others. I am trying the code below however when I run it I get the error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" on "Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Range(Lst).Activate".

```
Sub Copy1()
Dim Lst As Long
'save the rowNo
Lst = ActiveCell.Row

Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Activate
Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Range(Lst).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

Worksheets("Master Release Plan - HTSTG").Activate
Worksheets("Master Release Plan - HTSTG").Range(Lst).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

Worksheets("Inst. Gateway").Activate
Worksheets("Inst. Gateway").Range(Lst).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert


Worksheets("CAB").Activate
Worksheets("CAB").Range(Lst).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert

Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Range("A3:G5000").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Master Release Plan - HTSTG").Range("A3")

Worksheets("Master Release Plan - HTSTG").Range("A3:O5000").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("Inst. Gateway").Range("A3")

Worksheets("Inst. Gateway").Range("A3:T5000").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("CAB").Range("A3")

End Sub
```

I have tried "Dim Lst As Range" however then I get the error "Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" on "Lst = ActiveCell.Row".

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Glyn

New Code:

```
Sub InsertRow()

Dim Lst As Long
'save the rowNo
Lst = ActiveCell.Row

'Insert a row in each worksheet at the currently selected cell.
Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Rows(Lst).Insert
Worksheets("Master Release Plan - HTSTG").Unprotect
Worksheets("Master Release Plan - HTSTG").Rows(Lst).Insert
Worksheets("Inst. Gateway").Unprotect
Worksheets("Inst. Gateway").Rows(Lst).Insert
Worksheets("CAB").Unprotect
Worksheets("CAB").Rows(Lst).Insert
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the 2nd line of your code, you are assigning lst, a value(activecell.row), which is a long variable. if you write

```
Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Range(Lst).Activate
```

that means ex - Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Range(4).Activate, if ur activecell.row is 4. This will not work on a range.

If you want to select a row then change your existing line and all other similar lines, where you have range(lst)  to -

```
Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Rows(Lst).Activate
```

I would suggest not selecting anything on the sheet as far as possible because this may slow up the execution time. Your's is a very simple macro here but it is good practice to avoid selecting or activating stuff on your sheet as much as possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Bharath, I can not see my comment thanking you. My appologies I must not have saved it. Anyway, thank you very much, this works. Regards, Glyn.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Bharath 's answer it is not necassary and a generally bad idea to use `Select`.
Your row insertion code can be reduced to

```
Worksheets("Rel. Planning Meeting").Rows(Lst).Insert
Worksheets("Master Release Plan - HTSTG").Rows(Lst).Insert
Worksheets("Inst. Gateway").Rows(Lst).Insert
Worksheets("CAB").Rows(Lst).Insert
```

Comment: Didn't see your comment. Wanted to add something about selecting stuff. so edited my comment. +1 for showing how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement Chris, greatly appreciated. Regards, Glyn.