# VBA code for adding a row in two sheets at one time

Tags: excel, vba

I am not a programmer but have been filling that role as my company asks me to create worksheets for day to day processes so I apologize in advance if I do not state my question in the correct terms and if you have to break down your answer like you are talking to a total Noob as I am one.

Question:
I want to set up a button that will allow a user to add a row to the active sheet they are working on.  In the background I want the spreadsheet to add a row in another sheet in the same workbook in the same location as the one that was added.  (the two sheets are identical only with the non active worksheet having info from the previous month)  The reason I need it to do this is because the Active worksheet is pulling data from the inactive sheet and I want to keep the same number of rows in both sheets with the data on both in the same rows so it will pull the correct data.

Thank you for any advice you have!

Comment: Is the row being added the top row, a pre-determined row, or a selection based on the user?

Comment: This sounds like a headache. What if someone removes a row? What if they remove multiple rows at once? Are you going to lock down the page so that rows cannot be inserted or removed except via your code? The two pages shouldn't have to be synced up perfectly if the references already exist. Excel will update the address for the references upon a row insert.

Comment: Joe-based on a selection of the user.  The idea is they can add lines to a budget worksheet in order to further dissect the budget under one line item.

Comment: Daniel - It is a headache.  I need both sheets to line up because this file will get saved as a new file monthly....the idea being that the user can copy and paste data from current active sheet into the older sheet each month and then blow out the current months data and start the process over again.  It the cells don't line up it seems to cause issues with how data is being pulled.

Comment: This Works but with Errors that I can't Clear                    Sub AddRow()
'
' Row Macro

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CopyRow", RefersToR1C1:=Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

    Range("CopyRow").Select
    Selection.Copy
Dim Lst As Long
Lst = ActiveCell.Row

Worksheets("SOV Detailed Breakdown").Rows(Lst).Insert
Worksheets("Previous Application").Rows(Lst).Insert
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    ActiveWorkbook.Names("CopyRow").Delete
End Sub

Comment: got the idea from the following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715102/ms-excel-vba-how-to-insert-a-row-in-the-current-worksheet-and-three-others

Comment: To see code a little cleaner use link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989716/clearing-an-error-when-adding-rows-to-multiple-sheets  can't figure out how to do it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick play with the macro-recorder, I'm left with the following code:

```
Sub insertRow()
    Dim insertBeforeRow
    insertBeforeRow = 1

    ActiveSheet.Rows(insertBeforeRow).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' The following two lines are the same - both active the second sheet in the book
    Sheet2.Activate
    Sheets(2).Activate

    ActiveSheet.Rows(insertBeforeRow).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Then with a quick play with the debugger I see that the ActiveSheet has the property `index` - this is its index in the Sheets collection.
(click `ActiveSheet`, right-click and select Add Watch)

I come up with this (no error-checking, don't forget to add some! - Picking the last sheet in the workbook and running this will cause the dreaded "uh-uh no you don't dummy" error sound and message box)

```
Sub getActiveSheet()
    Dim curSheetIndex, numSheets, secondSheetIndex

    curSheetIndex = ActiveSheet.Index
    secondSheetIndex = curSheetIndex + 1

    ' the following two lines are equivalent - both operate on the Active Sheet
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Active Sheet"
    Sheets(curSheetIndex).Cells(1, 1) = "Active Sheet"

    ' finally, operate on the following sheet
    Sheets(secondSheetIndex).Cells(1, 1) = "Sheet following Active Sheet"
End Sub
```

You can weld the two snippets together in the manner that suits your purpose. The debugger in the VBA environment is a thing of beauty when it comes to discovering available functionality and properties. It's one of the reasons that I quite enjoy small tasks like this in VBA, to be honest. Its often quite quick 'n' easy to get the effect you're after, when at least a little familiar with the debugger and Excel's object model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for after rereading your post but I'll give it a shot.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    r0w = Selection.Row
    c0l = Selection.Column
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r0w, c0l).EntireRow.Insert
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r0w, c0l).EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

Looks like this works on my end.

Comment: Didn't work on my sheet.  Posting code I'm using above that is working (almost)

Comment: What errors are you receiving? Did you name your sheets correctly?