# Clearing an error when adding Rows to multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

*Question: I want to set up a button that will allow a user to add a row to the active sheet they are working on. In the background I want the spreadsheet to add a row in another sheet in the same workbook in the same location as the one that was added. (the two sheets are identical only with the non active worksheet having info from the previous month) The reason I need it to do this is because the Active worksheet is pulling data from the inactive sheet and I want to keep the same number of rows in both sheets with the data on both in the same rows so it will pull the correct data.*

I added copying the formulas from the selection row as well so the user does not need to copy manually and I think that is what is causing the issue.

Any idea on how to clear the error:

> Run-time error '1004':
> PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Got the idea for the code I used at [MS Excel VBA how to insert a row in the current worksheet and three others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715102/ms-excel-vba-how-to-insert-a-row-in-the-current-worksheet-and-three-others)

My code

```
Sub AddRow()
'
' Row Macro


    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="CopyRow", RefersToR1C1:=Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
    
    Range("CopyRow").Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    
    Dim Lst As Long

    Lst = ActiveCell.Row

    Worksheets("SOV Detailed Breakdown").Rows(Lst).Insert
    Worksheets("Previous Application").Rows(Lst).Insert
 
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


    ActiveWorkbook.Names("CopyRow").Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: This does everything I want it to but with errors.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error raises on the `PasteSpecial` method, which isn't necessary. When the clipboard is filled like this, the next `Insert` statement automatically does the paste operation.

I tidy it up to get rid of the `Name` assigment which I don't think you really need.

```
Sub AddRow() ' ' Row Macro
Dim Lst As Long

Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy

Lst = ActiveCell.Row

Worksheets("SOV Detailed Breakdown").Rows(Lst).Insert 
Worksheets("Previous Application").Rows(Lst).Insert

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code as above and it gave me a global failure error (did not like the line "Range(ActiveCell.Row).Copy  but I tried your advice and deleted the PasteSpecial and that did the trick.

Comment: Oops, try `Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Copy` instead of `Range...`